# Converting objects in multidimensional array to array

Tags: php, json, object, multidimensional-array

I am trying to get list of branches of the shipping company from their php API.The output from API I get is array which contains objects and I would like to convert these objects to arrays and save whole array to database. Example of the output is below. As I say I would like convert these objects into array and save it to database. Can you help me please? I tried some tips from stackoverflow but I have't fount anything yet. Thank you

```
Array
(
[email] => info@ulozenka.cz
[phone] => +420777208204
[hours] => UlozenkaLib\APIv3\Model\Branch\OpeningHours\OpeningHours Object
    (
        [regular:protected] => UlozenkaLib\APIv3\Model\Branch\OpeningHours\RegularOpeningHours Object
            (
                [monday:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => UlozenkaLib\APIv3\Model\Branch\OpeningHours\Hours Object
                            (
                                [open:protected] => 10:00
                                [close:protected] => 16:00
                            )
                    )
            )
        [exceptions:protected] => Array
            (
            )

    )
[links] => Array
    (
        [0] => UlozenkaLib\APIv3\Model\Link Object
            (
                [resourceName:protected] => website
                [url:protected] => https://www.ulozenka.cz/pobocky/50020/jablonec-nad-nisou-machova-877-4-czc-cz
            )

        [1] => UlozenkaLib\APIv3\Model\Link Object
            (
                [resourceName:protected] => picture
                [url:protected] => https://www.ulozenka.cz/cdn/images/branches/destination/50020.png
            )

        [2] => UlozenkaLib\APIv3\Model\Link Object
            (
                [resourceName:protected] => self
                [url:protected] => https://api.ulozenka.cz/v3/branches/50020
            )

    )

)
```

So the converted array should be

```
Array
(
[email] => info@ulozenka.cz
[phone] => +420777208204
[hours] => array
    (
        [regular] => Array
            (
                [monday] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [open] => 10:00
                                [close] => 16:00
                            )
                    )
            )
        [exceptions] => Array()

    )
[links] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [resourceName] => website
                [url] => https://www.ulozenka.cz/pobocky/50020/jablonec-nad-nisou-machova-877-4-czc-cz
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [resourceName] => picture
                [url] => https://www.ulozenka.cz/cdn/images/branches/destination/50020.png
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [resourceName] => self
                [url] => https://api.ulozenka.cz/v3/branches/50020
            )

    )

)
```

Comment: The usual way to save objects into a relational database (assuming that is the type of database you are using) is to use an ORM mapper. Not to convert them into arrays.

Comment: Apart from that... what is your specific question here? You have objects. And want to convert them. You just claim "I tried some tips from stackoverflow but I have't fount anything yet" but that does not help. Programming is not about looking around for snippets... _You_ need to understand what you are doing, you need to be able to implement yourself what you need. If you have a _specific_ issue you cannot solve, that is what this place can assist with. But we are not here to implement your code for you, sorry.